# Do the results agree with theoretical expectations? Explain why.

Tags: calculus, limits, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

Considering the function $$f(x) = \frac{(e^x -1)}{x}$$

Using L'Hospital's rule, it is shown that,$$lim_{x→0} f(x) = lim_{x→0}\frac{(e^x -1)}{x} =1$$

When checking the results, by writing a program to calculate f(x) for $x=10.0^{-k}, k =1,...15$,

Program L'HospitalApprox
implicit none

```
integer :: k
real :: x, f, abs_error

    x = 10.0**(-k)
    f = (exp(x)-1.0)/x
    abs_error = abs(1.0 - f)

    write(*,*) k, x, f, &
                             abs_error

end do
```

End Program L'HospitalApprox

Results:
[image: Picture describing results]

Could anyone please provide me with an in-detail explanation as to whether the results agree with theoretical expectations? While, also, explaining why?

Here are some points that I would like further clarifications on:

1. What is seen in terms of behaviour of the error as k increases?
2. By what rate does the error change?
3. What do you think might be causing that error change?

Comment: You may want to read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In single precision you will have $\exp(x)=1.0$ for $|x|\ll10^{-8}$. This is because, by the very same limit, you may see that $\exp(x)\approx1+x$, which rounds to $1$ if $x$ is too small.

In fact you can try this, replacing $\exp(x)$ with $1+x$ and get the same issue. See [here](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0LBVsEwVdfQhKtAQUPDULtCU9dQU7@CiwsmYYpLwgxV4v9/AA).

This issue is due catastrophic cancellation, where subtracting close floats leads to a loss of significant figures. This happens often when dealing with difference quotients.

To avoid this issue, you should either use more precision, stop before you lose too many figures, or estimate the limit a different way (for example, symmetric difference quotients converge faster).

In your particular case, you can look at the ratio of errors you got. For the first few steps, the errors decreased by a factor of almost exactly $0.1$ and then this started increasing, eventually leading to a completely wrong answer.

Comment: Hello, I reviewed this post since it is related to a homework that I am solving, I understand that the problem here is cancellation, but why when we work with the equivalent expression:$$f(x)=\frac{e^x-1}{ln(e^x)}$$ does it work correctly? As mentioned, $e^x = 1 + x$ and we have $ln(1 + x) = x$, and implementing a code similar to the one presented here, in Matlab with the equivalent expression the results agree with theoretical expectations and the error stabilizes with the approximation up to $k = 15$.

Comment: I think this phenomenon is due to the following, but I would like to know if I am correct, thanks in advance:
$$e^x-1\approx 0 \approx ln(1) \approx ln(e^x)$$

Comment: You are working with double precision. It's the same situation as originally here, but you have twice as many digits before $1+x$ will round to $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Accuracy problem, I suppose.

I give you below results computed with unlimited precision
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 k & f \\
 1 & 1.0517091807564762481 \\
 2 & 1.0050167084168057542 \\
 3 & 1.0005001667083416681 \\
 4 & 1.0000500016667083342 \\
 5 & 1.0000050000166667083 \\
 6 & 1.0000005000001666667 \\
 7 & 1.0000000500000016667 \\
 8 & 1.0000000050000000167 \\
 9 & 1.0000000005000000002 \\
 10 & 1.0000000000500000000 \\
 11 & 1.0000000000050000000 \\
 12 & 1.0000000000005000000 \\
 13 & 1.0000000000000500000 \\
 14 & 1.0000000000000050000 \\
 15 & 1.0000000000000005000 \\
 16 & 1.0000000000000000500 \\
 17 & 1.0000000000000000050 \\
 18 & 1.0000000000000000005 \\
 19 & 1.0000000000000000001 \\
 20 & 1.0000000000000000000
\end{array}
\right)$$ where you could notice nice patterns.

Comment: Which part of the problem do you think could lead to this accuracy problem? I am struggling to figure that out. Could you provide me with an explanation?

Comment: @Vic. The usual loss of precision. I made the same using double precision and it is fine upi to $k=10$  for which $f=1.000000000341$ which is wrong. For $11 \leq k \leq 19$, $f$ starts to be chaotic but "close" to $1$ and for $k \geq 20$, $f=0$. Same as for you.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt. Thanks for pointing my error !